# RStudio: 16Gb RAM not enough to open 1.6Gb .Rdata file?

Tags: r

I need to open a Rdata file to convert it to dta format. Running Rstudio 1.0.136 with 64bit R; Windows 10; Core i5, 16Gb RAM; 500Gb SSD.

When I try to open a 1.6Gb Rdata file, RAM use on Windows resource monitor increases gradually from 2Gb to 15.9 Gb and then I get an error: cannot allocate vector of size 30.8 Mb.

Is there a way to overcome this problem without increasing RAM (motherboard will only take 16Gb)?

Comment: Note that .Rdata files are compressed by default.

Comment: `save`, which creates .Rdata files has a built-in compression feature. So, it is natural that loading such a file would increase memory use beyond the file size. Examples in the compression section of `?save` show compression ratios of 1.3 to 4.9. The compression ratio of >10 that you are seeing is not be inconceivable given these numbers.

Comment: Depending on how much money you have, you could spin up a virtual machine in the cloud with enough memory, upload your file, and open it there. The [Azure Data Science VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/microsoft-ads/standard-data-science-vm/) is an example of a VM that comes with R preinstalled. Both Windows and Linux flavours are available.

Comment: Thank you, Hong Ooi, I am trying to set up a Data Science VM. Shouldn't be too expensive since I only need it to open a file.

Comment: If you are working with large objects that don't fit in memory, there are a number of very good packages that allow you keep those objects on disk and still access subsets quickly.  My favorite is the "ff" package.

Comment: Thank you, @thc, I may have to look into the "ff" package. The difficulty with this approach is that I haven't used R before - it will be a lot of learning just to open and convert a file into Stata format.